# How to append the HTML results of a URL call to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

I have a URL that resides on another domain, like this:

```
http://ads.adserver.com/ad?site=1233&zone=45435
```

When you type this URL in the browser, the result is HTML like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target=""><img src="htt://ads.adserver.com/i/image.gif" border="0"/></a><br/><a href="http://ads.adserver.com/redir/12313" target="">Test</a>
```

The above renders as an image wrapped in a link with a second link below it.

I tried to capture this URL in a script tag and append it to the DOM, but it does not render the HTML above.

```
var ad_script = document.createElement('script');

ad_script.type = 'text/javascript';
ad_script.src = 'http://ads.adserver.com/ad?site=1233&zone=45435';

li.appendChild(ad_script);
```

Are there any other ways of invoking this URL and putting the result on the page?  I can't use $.getScript() since I'm not invoking this in the global context.  I need this HTML to appear exactly where I want it to appear.

EDIT: The only reason I am trying this route is that the third-party does not provide a JSON-P interface.

EDIT2: Unfortunately, I am not on an application server.

EDIT3: This is for iPhone.

Comment: I don't see any way to accomplish this without a proper JSONP service on their end or without an application server.  Your problem is that what is being returned isn't a script, so appending it to the DOM isn't going to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are limited to how you load this due to cross-domain issues .. an easy way would be to load the image in it's own iframe

```
<iframe src='http://ads.adserver.com/ad?site=1233&zone=45435' height='200px' width='200px' />
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, because it allows me to get passed the cross-domain problem.  However, I forgot to mention that this is viewed on the iPhone/WebKit platform, and I have heard that iframe support is a bit glitchy.

Comment: I have just tried this in an iPhone, and the URL loads, but the iframe is glitchy.  I am going to have to talk to the vendor to see if there is JSON-P support. :-(

Comment: JSON-P support would make this much much easier .. then use a javascript templating engine to render the way you need view it

Answer (score 1):

<s>You'll want to use ajax for this. The easiest way might be jQuery's .load() method.</s>

Assuming the element you want the content to go into has an id of `holder`, you would do

```
('#holder').load('http://ads.adserver.com/ad?site=1233&zone=45435')
```

It will put the contents of the webpage into your selected element. http://api.jquery.com/load/

edit: Sorry, forgot cross-site ajax limitations. You could instead set up a php page like:

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
    echo file_get_contents($_GET['url'])
}
```

and then do

```
('#holder').load('http://yoursite.com/yourpage.php?url=http://ads.adserver.com/ad?site=1233&zone=45435')
```

Comment: I received a HTTP 200 error.  The URL is on another domain, so I got stopped by cross-domain security.

Comment: @Stephen, Did you try the second bit of code with a php page, or the first part?

Comment: I am unable to run your second part (the edited addition), because our platform is not on a web application server.  We have a build process that creates static HTML files as the output, which is why I am trying to find client-side only solutions.

Comment: @Stephen, Yikes, that's not going to be easy. As shown by the error, cross-site scripting is not allowed. All I can think of now is an external website you own that you can set up script on to return jsonp.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help out.  I am going to ask if the third-party has a JSON-P service, or we will have to change the business requirements.

Comment: @Stephen, Alright, good luck. It would be quite easy to do what I mentioned in the last comment though. All you would need is another server that has php to host the page you need. I don't mean move your entire website to another server, but rather have one page set up there.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I work in a large organization, so I don't think I can convince the organization to open up a PHP or other application server to set this up.  I will definitely keep this idea in mind in the future if I have that kind of flexibility.

Comment: @Stephen, Well as a LAST resort, you could even use free hosting like 000webhost or x10hosting to put the php page on. Let us know if you do find something though!

Answer (score 0):

Take the jsonp approach. use an actual script tag and put an executing javascript function as the response that adds that html markup to the dom. It will add it to the dom of the page where the script tag resides.

Comment: The third-party in question does not provide a JSON-P interface.  They have a JSON interface, but since this would be a cross-domain request from my domain to that third-party domain, the browser security model will not let $.getJSON() or $.ajax() get the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of jQuery ajax calls that can accomplish this, for example:
   jQuery.get('http://ads.adserver.com/ad?site=1233&zone=45435', function(data){jQuery(updateElementQuery).html(data);});

Comment: The same origin policy forbids this.

Comment: I receive a HTTP 200 request, so I think the browser is rejecting the request as it is a cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [jquery method 'load'](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
`$('#result').load(url, function(response) {

   $('#my-li').append($('#result').html());

   $('#result').html(null);

});`
```

... where `#result` is some hidden `div`

Comment: Sorry, this results in a cross-domain error.  The URL is on another domain, so this won't work.